Is the use of an optocoupler necessary for a relay circuit?
Given that relays inherently provide isolation and separate the control circuit from the power circuit, why is an optocoupler placed in the control circuit section of relays in industrial boards?


As noted in the answer  having the input ground the same as the power ground means the optoisolators are unnecessary. See also What is "Arduino Optocoupler Disease"?

Given the circuit as you have drawn it (the input ground is the same as the power ground), then, no, optoisolators are unnecessary. (Indeed they waste a bit of power.) You could connect R1 directly to a Darlington transistor's base and achieve the same performance. A reverse diode between the base and ground would protect the base.
In a commercial relay module (the input ground is isolated from the power ground), then, yes, an opto-isolator adds flexibility. It lets you control the relay with any voltage source, be it referenced to the same ground, a different ground, or a positive rail. It also cuts any ground loop.

However, many relay boards on the market still do not have a separate input for power supply. They probably add the optocoupler just to give a sense of industrial feel!

In much the same way that the relay isolates the output circuit from the control circuit, the opto is there to isolate the input circuit from the control circuit.  Thus, in your schematic, you could have a 48 Vdc input to a 12 Vdc control circuit to a 480 Vac output circuit.
It's all in the Grounds.  If two circuits with different DC operating voltages have a common ground, then galvanic isolation is not possible.  In that situation, an opto still can have other benefits, such as level shifting, logic polarity inversion, and lowpass filtering.

Lets say I have a 12V rail for the relays from which I regulate 5V to the uC. Would that justify the optos so that the 5V rail is cleaner? Not the circuit in the question, just to be clear what I mean.

@devnull No it does not justify the optos. It will have no effect on the 5V rail. You can drive the transistor base with same current than the opto LED for no effect on 5V at all. In this circuit, the optos do not provide any isolation at all.

It's clear now. Thank you.

No, an optocoupler is not necessary. This is proven by perfectly well working relay circuits that don't have an optocoupler, otherwise all relay circuits would have an optocoupler.
The circuit you have drawn has an optocoupler for no apparent reason.
The control signal could go to transistor base directly
It is definitely not used for isolation.
It may serve a purpose when the transistor fails and passes relay DC back to control circuit, but then again, with the price of an optocoupler, you could just design the circuit better to protect against that.

Actually, it absolutely is used for isolation.

@AnalogKid No it isn't. There is same ground on both sides of the opto - so it provides no isolation. Same level of "isolation" can be achieved with simply by driving the transistor with MCU directly.
